# Overcoming newlines with grep -o

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, json

I have a file similar to such:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "stats": {
      "name": "some-file",
      "uris": [
        "some-example.com"
      ],
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 8080,
      "uptime": 168,
      "mem_quota": 2147483648,
      "disk_quota": 2147483648,
      "fds_quota": 16384,
      "usage": {
        "time": "2016-09-13 07:39:40 +0000",
        "cpu": 0.30315522606369516,
        "mem": 1069568000,
        "disk": 237203456
      }
    }
  },
  "0": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "stats": {
      "name": "some-file2",
      "uris": [
        "some-example-e.com"
      ],
      "host": "127.0.0.2",
      "port": 8081,
      "uptime": 169,
      "mem_quota": 2147483648,
      "disk_quota": 2147483648,
      "fds_quota": 16384,
      "usage": {
        "time": "2016-09-13 07:39:40 +0000",
        "cpu": 0.3086296386531593,
        "mem": 1073180672,
        "disk": 237203456
      }
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "stats": {
      "name": "some-file3",
      "uris": [
        "some-example.com"
      ],
      "host": "127.1.20.3",
      "port": 8190,
      "uptime": 168,
      "mem_quota": 2147483648,
      "disk_quota": 2147483648,
      "fds_quota": 16384,
      "usage": {
        "time": "2016-09-13 07:39:40 +0000",
        "cpu": 0.31213565359044587,
        "mem": 1072861184,
        "disk": 237203456
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I require to extract the values of the cpu, mem and disk and put it in a file in format as so:

```
0.30315522606369516,1069568000,237203456,0.3086296386531593,1073180672
```

Basically, it should be

```
first_instance_cpu,first_instance_mem,first_instance_disk,second_instance_cpu,second_instance_mem...
```

I hope you get the point.

I'm using the following `grep` statement to retrieve these values.

```bsh
grep -Eow '"(cpu|mem|disk)": [0-9.]+' SampleOutput | grep '[0-9.]'
```

And this gives me output as follows

```
"cpu": 0.30315522606369516
"mem": 1069568000
"disk": 237203456
"cpu": 0.3086296386531593
"mem": 1073180672
"disk": 237203456
"cpu": 0.31213565359044587
"mem": 1072861184
"disk": 237203456
```

With the numbers I want highlighted in red (matching). Now, I want only the numbers but when I use the `-o` option with my second `grep` command, I get the numbers, sure, but each on a different line like so

```
0
.
3
3
1
```

...and so on.

How do I get the results as at least whole numbers on different lines? Then I could use tr or something to comma separate them.

Comment: Use a json tool for json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ grep -Po '"(cpu|mem|disk)": \K[\d.]+' SampleOutput | paste -sd , -
0.30315522606369516,1069568000,237203456,0.3086296386531593,1073180672,237203456,0.31213565359044587,1072861184,237203456
```

`grep` implementations that support `-o` generally also support `-P` for PCRE where `\K` (in PCRE Version 7.2 19-Jun-07 or above) can be used to reset the start of the matching text (so `grep -o` only outputs what's matched on the right of it).

You were not far in your approach, you just had to replace `grep -o '[0-9.]'` with `grep -oE '[0-9.]+'`, that is find *sequences* of one or more digits or dot instead of just one digit or dot.

Answer (score 7):

Since your file is in JSON format I'll use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq '
    flatten |
    map(.stats.usage | del(.time)) |
    map([.cpu, .mem, .disk]) |
    flatten |
    .[]' <file.json | \
paste -sd ,
```

Output:

```
0.30315522606369516,1069568000,237203456,0.3086296386531593,1073180672,237203456,0.31213565359044587,1072861184,237203456
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `jq` solution:

```
jq -r '.[].stats.usage|[.cpu,.mem,.disk]|@csv'  f.json
```